# Access Violation Exception Thrown OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, exception, opencv3.0, opencv3.2

Im working on a simple face detector using Visual Studio 2017 with OpenCV 3.2.0 and haarcascades.
Whenever i run this, i get an error saying there's an exception thrown right after i create the first point. Access violation error. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I do not see any error in the code. [image: Here is a picture of the exception thrown.]

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>



using namespace std;
using namespace cv; 

int main()
{
    CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
    CascadeClassifier eye_cascade;
    face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
    eye_cascade.load("haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml");
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat frame;
    while (cap.read(frame))
    {
        Mat frame_gray;
        std::vector <Rect> faces;
        cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);
        face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray,faces, 1.1, 2,0,Size(30,30),Size(300,300));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size();i++)
        {


            Point first(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
            Point second(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
            rectangle(frame,second,first, cvScalar(255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);

        }

        imshow("Test", frame_gray);
        waitKey(30);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the full names of OpenCV libraries you're linking with?

Comment: opencv_world320d.lib

Comment: OK, good, so you're not mixing debug and release, that's a common issue. Now, did you build this OpenCV library yourself, or if not, where did it come from? (My point being, was it built with MSVS 2017?)

Comment: i tried this with VS 2015, same issue. These are all libraries I downloaded off the OpenCV website. I don't have issues with linking since I'm able to stream the webcam footage using OpenCV library.

Comment: Do you believe this might be a system error? I do have ubuntu installed in a dual boot setup.

Comment: Try building your own copy of OpenCV from sources, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: You could try it in Ubuntu, although I can't see anything serious there. I definitely can't see any normal way you could end up with a vector of 10^18 or so elements, so there's some kind of memory corruption happening there. Smells a bit like an problem of mixed runtimes.